# using a predefined String in a GUI

Tags: java, string, user-interface, output

I have my GUI set up the way I want it now I'm trying to output a string called AnswerKey i have predefined in dashReplace() I tried to draw the string and use JLabel but i just can't seem to find the right method of doing such.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.*;



public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5793357804828609325L;

    public static String answerKey() {
        //get random array element
        String array[] = new String[10];
        array[0] = "hamlet";
        array[1] = "mysts of avalon";
        array[2] = "the iliad";
        array[3] = "tales from edger allan poe";
        array[4] = "the children of hurin";
        array[5] = "the red badge of courage";
        array[6] = "of mice and men";
        array[7] =  "utopia"; 
        array[8] =  "chariots of the gods";
        array[9] =  "a brief history of time";

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String s = list.get(0);
        return s;
    }

    public static StringBuilder dashReplace(String s) {
        //replace non-white space char with dashes and creates StringBuilder Object
        String tW = s.replaceAll("\\S", "-"); 
        System.out.print(tW + "\n");  
        StringBuilder AnswerKey = new StringBuilder(tW);
        return AnswerKey;
    }




    public HangmanPanel(){
        this.setLayout(null);

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Welcome to the Hangman App");
        JButton Button = new JButton("Ok");
        //Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);  
        JLabel tfLable = new JLabel("Please Enter a Letter:");

        //trying to out put predefined string
        JLabel AnswerKey = new JLabel(AnswerKey);

        JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
        //String input = text.getText();

        heading.setSize(200, 50);
        tfLable.setSize(150, 50);
        text.setSize(50, 30);
        Button.setSize(60, 20);

        heading.setLocation(300, 10);
        tfLable.setLocation(50, 40);
        text.setLocation(50, 80);
        Button.setLocation(100, 85);

        this.add(heading);
        this.add(tfLable);
        this.add(text);
        this.add(Button);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is called `answerKey`, not `AnswerKey`. In fact, this surely won't compile as you've currently written it - you're trying to assign a variable to something while using that variable as a constructor parameter. It should be:

```
JLabel AnswerKey = new JLabel(dashReplace(answerKey()).toString());
```

To make this work, however, you'll need to make the method non-`static`. Also, having a variable named `AnswerKey` and a method named `answerKey` is just crying out for confusion - I'd suggest a better name for the `JLabel`.

Comment: @Sage1216: As Yuushi points out (1+ to his answer) you will want to learn and adhere to Java naming conventions, including being sure that variable and method names begin with a lower-case letter and class names with an upper-case letter. This is important, especially if you are desiring that others (i.e., your instructors and *us*) easily and fully understand your code so that we can more easily help you (or grade you). Good luck!

Comment: thank you... I will try to adhere to Java naming conventions in the future at the moment though i only have three day to get this done and I've never used a GUI interface before... I don't know if i have time to rename my methods and classes